# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type smallint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

Running a select statement against a table with a column of smallint and receiving above error:

```
SELECT * FROM [Database].[dbo].[TableName]
where ColumnName = 'ABC123'
```

I know smallint needs to be an integer but in the table, the data contains mixed data (i.e. ABC123); how can I run the select statement without modifying the datatype? When I try to modify the datatype, SQL tells me I need to drop and recreate the table which I cannot do...

Thanks!

Comment: what data type is ColumnName in your example? - if Column name is a small int then there is no possible way it contains the varchar value 'ABC123'

Comment: The datatype for ColumnName is smallint which is part of the problem I know - but I assure the column contains varchar values. I was able to figure out how to get the results by using "cast' on the where clause. See my answer below. This worked, thanks!

Comment: The SMALLINT data type accepts numeric values with an implied scale of zero. It stores any integer value between the range 2^ -15 and 2^15 -1. Attempting to assign values outside this range causes an error. - ColumnName can not be a smallint if you are storing varchar values

Comment: I understand what a smallint data type is however, in this column in our database, it contains both smallint values and mixed character values... which is why I was doing a little digging on how to get the results. Thanks!

Comment: But the actual datatype of the column physically can not be small int -

Answer (score 4):

Using Cast I was able to get the results:

```
select * from TableName
where cast(ColumnName as varchar) = 'ABC123'
```

This worked and returned the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to select numbers only. If you are trying to search across multiple columns, you would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Database].[dbo].[TableName]
where SmallIntColumn = 123 AND CharColumn = 'ABC'
```

If the column is some type of numeric, it could not contain non-numeric entries.

Comment: thank you but I actually figured it out! I will edit my question to include the answer. Thanks though.